# git error when using git submodule update --init

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm getting an error when using the following command on zsh:

```
git submodule update --init
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
fatal: No url found for submodule path 'bundle/YCM' in .gitmodules
```

The problem is, when I go to my .gitmodules file I have the following lines defined:

```
[submodule "/home/username/.vim/bundle/YCM"]
    path = /home/username/.vim/bundle/YCM
    url = https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe
```

Where `username` is my actual user.
I installed the YCM plugin via

```
git submodule add https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe ~/.vim/bundle/YCM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths are supposed to be relative to the repository root, e.g.

```
[submodule "bundle/YCM"]
    path = bundle/YCM
    url = https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe
```

From `gitmodules(5)`:

> Defines the path, **relative to the top-level directory** of the Git working tree,
>   where the submodule is expected to be checked out. The path name must not end
>   with a /. All submodule paths must be unique within the .gitmodules file.